# How to avoid re-formatting of file in GitHub browser editor?

Tags: git, github, editor, edit

I am trying to edit a file in a project on GitHub online on the browser editor by clicking the `pencil icon` [image: pencil icon] on top-right corner of the file.

The issue is, as soon as the browser opens the file for editing, if I click on `Preview Changes` ***without even making any changes to the file***, it shows::
`@@ -1,373 +1,373 @@` diff.

[image: Diff Changes]

This most probably must be happening due to the reformatting of the file. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Cop-out answer: Don't use GitHub web for editing source files, GitHub wasn't created for this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I understand what you mean but then if they have added this feature, it should work, right. Because not all of us are proficient in git commands. Does it mean that the editor they use is buggy and couldn't save the previous formatting of the file?

Comment: If you didn't do anything, then yes, your guess that line endings are responsible is probably on the right track.  Try to see if you can find a setting for preserving line endings.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Couldn't find any setting on the site.

Comment: Do this: Edit a UNIX line ending file _and_ a Windows line ending file from the GitHub client.  See how the two files change.  I am asking you to do this so that maybe we can find out which line ending scheme GitHub web is using.